# Set default input language for bootup

Tags: login, windows-8, input-languages

When I boot up, my default input language is Hebrew. I can change the language when I boot up, (click on it, etc) but I really just want it to be English by default.

Additionally, should I attempt to sign into a different user, and then back into the first account it will automatically change the input language to English.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

**Note:** I already have English set above Hebrew.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see if the following helps?

- From the location in your screenshot, click on `Advanced settings`
- Click on `Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts and new user accounts`:

  [image]
- Click on the `Administrative tab` and then the `Copy settings` button:

  [image]
- Select both the `Copy your current settings to` check-boxes:

  [image]